# Firefox: no messages for html5 form validation?

Tags: forms, html, validation, firefox

Does firefox have built-in messages for validating html5 forms? Messages show up in Chrome, but all firefox does is leave a red border on the inside of an input such as

```
input#password name="password" type="password" required pattern="^\S{6,}$" maxlength="20" ||
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try your testcase, I see a little "Please fill out this field" message drop down if the field is empty and "Please match the requested format" drop down if I put in a short password.  So Firefox (at least Firefox 9) does this fine in general.